# Trying to mock "new" through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is in my controller

```
@business = @current_user.businesses.new(params[:business])
```

`@businesses` is an array of `business` objects and I'm unsure of how to mock this cascade of calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The 'businesses' part of it is an association proxy. So usually mock it like this:

```
business = Business.new
businesses_proxy = mock('business association proxy', :new => business)
@current_user.should_receive(:businesses).and_return(businesses_proxy)
```

or more explicit

```
business = Business.new
businesses_proxy = mock('business association proxy')
businesses_proxy.should_recieve(:new).and_return(business)
@current_user.should_receive(:businesses).and_return(businesses_proxy)
```

Comment: This is a super old post but it just saved my bacon! Thanks!